# Is the image loaded from url in winforms picturebox stored in cache?

Tags: winforms, caching, picturebox

In a form in winform application i have to show images (multiple images) stored on webserver. There is no problem in showing images as i can simple assign URL to picturebox.

```
picturebox1.ImageLocation = "http://example.com/Image.jpg";
```

That form will be opened many times frequently, right now each time form is opened, images are being downloaded every time. It is unnecessary increasing traffic.

Is it possible to tell picturebox to cache image (as Browser do), so next time same images is requested, it should load quickly.
Is that possible?

Comment: I tried http sniffer and i found that it is downloading image every time form opened. I am showing 12 images in 12 pictureboxes.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-load the image(s) with
`Image img = Image.FromFile("...");`

Then you can give the image to the PictureBox:
`pictureBox1.Image = img;`

Comment: `Image.FromFile` can't load HTTP urls

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image in a temp folder and check the temp the folder first when opening the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

First Create a function to check whether file exist or not. If exist then simply load the file from local path else download the file from URL and store it in local.

```
//Function to validate the local cache file

    private Image load_image()
    {
       Image img=null;
        if(!(File.Exists(@"d:\samp.png")))
        {
            using (HttpClient httpclient= new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = httpclient.GetAsync(@"https://i.imgur.com/Jb6lTp1.png");
                if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return img;
                }
                using (var fs= new FileStream(@"d:\samp.png",FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    response.Result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
              
            }
        }
        img = Image.FromFile(@"d:\samp.png");
       return img;
    }
 
 //calling the function of click event

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = load_image();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```