# How can i switch between two icons to make them flash smooth?

Tags: c#, winforms

In top of form1 constructor i did:

```
filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\bout0_000\Downloads\", "imagenew*.ico");
timer3.Start();
```

Then:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!filePaths[i].Equals(currentIcon))
        {
            this.Icon = new Icon(filePaths[i]);
            currentIcon = filePaths[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the designer of form1 i added the Icon of this icon and when I'm running the program the icons switch and flashing fast and good.

**But in the taskbar the icon is not switching fast and smooth enough** it seems for some seconds it's flashing good and then some seconds it's like hanging for milisecond or some it's not switching fast and smooth like in the form1 Icon.

Comment: That sounds like you're hanging on IO, are you reading the icon data immediately before attempting to display it?

Comment: Cache your icons. You may inadvertently leak GDI handles since you are setting new everytime.

Comment: You might want to load all icons in the constructor and try to update them from existing memory, hm? As TyCobb said, cache it.

Comment: I tried it with Icons in the Resources and they blink just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the System.Timers.Timer operates on an independent thread, so your main thread and whatever work it's doing wouldn't be blocking the `+Elapsed` event.

Maybe it's an issue with constantly, over and over and over, reading the file from the drive to toggle the icon graphic?     My suggestion would be to load your targeted images into a resource file for your project, and draw the swapping of images from *that*, instead of the physical drive.

If those files are dynamic, maybe cache them up on program initialization.

[Is the image loaded from url in winforms picturebox stored in cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072133/is-the-image-loaded-from-url-in-winforms-picturebox-stored-in-cache)