# How to cache images from PictureBox in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, caching

Im trying to load images from a website. It loads very slowly. Everytime its selected. Any way to cache the image.

```
picturebox1.ImageLocation = "http://example.com/Image.jpg";
```

That form will be opened many times frequently, right now each time form is opened, images are being downloaded every time. It is unnecessary increasing traffic.

Is it possible to tell PictureBox to cache image (as Browser do), so next time same images is requested, it should load quickly. Is this possible?

```
   if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "Explore any game with Dex";
            Image img = Image.FromFile("https://i.imgur.com/Jb6lTp1.png");
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

It says given path format is not supported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the image loaded from url in winforms picturebox stored in cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072133/is-the-image-loaded-from-url-in-winforms-picturebox-stored-in-cache)

Comment: @Martheen Well it is. The answer he gave was not working

Comment: What *is* not working? Show us your code

Comment: The answer from that dupe isn't meant to be used that way. You're supposed to create your own function to handle caching of URL, so save to file system on new URL, and simply pass the existing file for the existing URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

First Create a function to check whether file exist or not. If exist then simply load the file from local path else download the file from URL and store it in local.

```
//Function to validate the local cache file

    private Image load_image()
    {
       Image img=null;
        if(!(File.Exists(@"d:\samp.png")))
        {
            using (HttpClient httpclient= new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = httpclient.GetAsync(@"https://i.imgur.com/Jb6lTp1.png");
                if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return img;
                }
                using (var fs= new FileStream(@"d:\samp.png",FileMode.CreateNew))  // Path can be added as parameter of function
                {
                    response.Result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
              
            }
        }
        img = Image.FromFile(@"d:\samp.png");
       return img;
    }
 
 //calling the function of click event

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
        richTextBox1.Text = "Explore any game with Dex";
        pictureBox1.Image = load_image();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: Handle the exceptions where ever required. Use parameters in function as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use PictureBox's `Load` method in the `Form1_Load` event. Also make sure the URL is valid.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Load("https://www.nippon.com/en/ncommon/contents/japan-data/169591/169591.jpg");
}
```

Comment: That doesnt save the image. It still takes time if I choose something else and then that